# Division in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, division

What's the difference between `/` and `\` for division in VB.NET?

My code gives very different answers depending on which I use. I've seen both before, but I never knew the difference.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are two ways to divide numbers.  The fast way and the slow way.  A lot of compilers try to trick you into doing it the fast way.  C# is one of them, try this:

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine(1 / 2);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output: 0

Are you happy with that outcome?  It is technically correct, documented behavior when the left side and the right side of the expression are integers.  That does a fast *integer division*.  The IDIV instruction on the processor, instead of the (infamous) FDIV instruction.  Also entirely consistent with the way all curly brace languages work.  But definitely a major source of "wtf happened" questions at SO.  To get the happy outcome you would have to do something like this:

```
    Console.WriteLine(1.0 / 2);
```

Output: 0.5

The left side is now a double, forcing a floating point division.  With the kind of result your calculator shows.  Other ways to invoke FDIV is by making the right-side a floating point number or by explicitly casting one of the operands to (double).

VB.NET doesn't work that way, the / operator is **always** a floating point division, irrespective of the types.  Sometimes you really *do* want an integer division.  That's what `\` does.

Comment: Interesting point you brought up. I always understood the difference between / and \ in VB, but it never crossed my mind for some reason that this is doing the work that specifying data types does in C languages. Guess I can go back and remove all the D's and F's from the end of my numbers now. =)

Answer (score 12):

```
10 / 3 = 3.333
10 \ 3 = 3 (the remainder is ignored)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
/ Division
\ Integer Division
```

Comment: Some elaboration might be in order.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Actually, nope, that's a perfectly concise summary that told me exactly what I wanted to know. Though the first line could've specified "floating point division".

Answer (score 2):

```
10 / 3 = 3.33333333333333, assigned to integer = 3
10 \ 3 = 3, assigned to integer = 3
20 / 3 = 6.66666666666667, assigned to integer = 7
20 \ 3 = 6, assigned to integer = 6
```

Code for the above:

```
Dim a, b, c, d As Integer
a = 10 / 3
b = 10 \ 3
c = 20 / 3
d = 20 \ 3

Debug.WriteLine("10 / 3 = " & 10 / 3 & ", assigned to integer = " & a)
Debug.WriteLine("10 \ 3 = " & 10 \ 3 & ", assigned to integer = " & b)
Debug.WriteLine("20 / 3 = " & 20 / 3 & ", assigned to integer = " & c)
Debug.WriteLine("20 \ 3 = " & 20 \ 3 & ", assigned to integer = " & d)
```