# VB.NET: Increase the Value of a variable by 1 in every $100 purchase

Tags: vb.net

I have written a code that helps registrars for their job. They have a promo that in every $100 purchase a point will be added on the costumer's account. Now, I don't know how to write the code for that. Example:

If a value of a variable `x is 189` a point will be added in y variable so

```
y = 1
```

now, when `189 increases to 200` a point will be added again in y, so

```
y = 2
```

now, and so on and so forth.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Math.Floor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.floor%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
Dim x As Int32 = 189
Dim y As Int32 = CInt(Math.Floor(x / 100))
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/CF0uuE)

> Returns the largest integer less than or equal to the specified number.

Comment: Ohh.. Thank you, I just have to put it in a function, Thanks again!

Comment: @XtraCode: You're welcome. But why you need an extra method? `Math.Floor` is already one ;)

Comment: I have to use the code every time I press a button so I have to put it in a sub or a function. Using a code repeatedly is inefficient so I have so use a sub or a func and call it everytime I need It :)

Answer (score 2):

most simple way is

```
y = x \ 100
```

[Division in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341611/division-in-vb-net)

Comment: +1 i'll never remember [this operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e16fywh.aspx) ;)