# Integer division rounding in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

When two variables are declared as integer type and you perform

14/4, you get 4, but when you use integer division, 14\4, you get 3.

I thought when you use integer division it rounds to the closest even number. So 14\4 = 3.5 (4 is the closest even number) should be 4 instead,
right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Division in vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341611/division-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you cast a floating point number to an integer in VB.NET, the value is rounded to the nearest even number. Apparently rounding a number when converting it to an integer is a behavior that stretches back to the days of the BASIC language.

However, when performing integer division (with the `\` operator), the fractional part is simply discarded, no matter what the fractional part is. This is why you get the behavior that you are seeing.

Comment: This is not correct. Division in VB.Net does not follow the same rules as in C#. In VB.Net, when dividing using the `/` operator, the arguments (and the result) will be promoted to double. When you want to do the C#-like integer division, you should use the \ operator.

Comment: he means \ probably, 14/4 = 4 14\4 = 3

Comment: 14/4 = 3.5 in VB.Net, unless you are casting to Integer. https://ideone.com/qkrlIR

Comment: ... the question title is "vb.net integer division rounding"

Comment: @lesderid What part of what I said is incorrect? "14 / 4 is 3.5" is exactly what I said (though I was talking about mathematics in general).

Comment: @JLRishe I probably misread, but this is over a year ago, so I'm not sure haha. Consider it a misunderstanding. :)

Comment: Stackoverflow answers like this is great for the growing numbers of us who've been programming for 50 years.  (You'll get there before you know it, and look at all the money you'll have made!)

Answer (score 11):

In VB.NET, the `/` operator is defined to return a floating-point result. It converts the variables to double before performing the division.

This is not the case in the integer division `\` where the division is performed without the remainder if the quotient is a decimal (decimals are ignored). For example if the quotient is `3.x`, then `x` is ignored

Comment: my question is  why the 3.5 is rounding to 3 when using integer division instead of 4

Comment: because in integer division the decimals of quotient are ignored. So in `3.x`, `x` is ignored

Comment: Thank you for this...  I was trying to figure out why 15/2 was coming out as 8 instead of 7...  This doesn't explain it, but it does fix it.